# Remove ASP.NET Machine Account from Windows 8.1 Start screen

Tags: windows, windows-8.1-preview

After installing Windows 8.1 preview release, there's a `ASP.NET Machine Account` at the Start screen. I don't remember seeing it before the 8.1 install. Now the question is how do I remove it from the list without removing or disabling the account?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to hide this account without breaking whatever functionality it is providing:

1. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> key combination to open the Run window, type `regedit` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. In the Register Editor window, navigate to the following registry key:
   **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\Userlist**. If the *SpecialAccounts* key and *Userlist* keys do not exist then create them.
3. On the right hand side of *Userlist*, right-click on any blank space, and point to **New** -> **DWORD (32-bit) Value**.
4. Name the new DWORD registry value name exactly with the user name used at the logon screen. (In this case, `ASP.NET Machine Account`)
5. Double-click on DWORD registry value, and set the value data to **0** in order to hide the account from Welcome Screen. To display the user account on Welcome Screen again so that it’s visible again, delete the registry entry, or set the value data to **1**.
6. Exit Registry Editor. Log off or restart computer to make the change effective.

Comment: I no longer have the preview version so couldn't verify the steps above, but it seem a good option for others still have this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Previous answer hasn't worked for me, so I disabled Fast User Switching.

1. Open regedit and go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
2. Look for a value called “HideFastUserSwitching“. If it does not exist, right-click the “System” folder, select “New DWORD 32-bit value“, then type a name of “HideFastUserSwitching“. Press “Enter” to create the value.
3. Double-click “HideFastUserSwitching“. Change the “Value data” to “1” to disable Fast User Switching.

Source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e3c13fbc-f411-49e4-b9cb-1229a7b6102a/hide-a-user-account-at-windows-10-home-welcome-signin-screen-dichotomy?forum=win10itprogeneral